# Ubuntu fails to install

Tags: installation, partitioning, usb

After installing Ubuntu from a USB drive, it says that it will restart.

This should be fine but as soon as it opens up again it goes back to the "Try Ubuntu or Install" window. When I check my partition it says it's empty. I have no idea how to install it properly because, frankly, my computer knowledge is lacking a lot!

Comment: Could you tell which version are you installing? Also, what is your computer's make and model?

Answer (score 2):

If it says your partition is empty, yet asks you if you want to install Ubuntu, am I wrong to infer you left the USB key in the computer whilst rebooting?